# React SlidingPane header getting hidden under Nav bar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

This is my App.js:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <NavigationBar />
                <Routes />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is where I am using a SlidingPane on a button click:
Product.js:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isPaneOpen: false,
            isPaneOpenLeft: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ isPaneOpen: true })}>Click me to open right pane!</button>
            <div style={{ marginTop: '32px' }}>
                <button onClick={ () => this.setState({ isPaneOpenLeft: true }) }>
                    Click me to open left pane with 20% width!
                </button>
            </div>
            <SlidingPane
                className='some-custom-class'
                overlayClassName='some-custom-overlay-class'
                isOpen={ this.state.isPaneOpen }
                title='Hey, it is optional pane title.  I can be React component too.'
                subtitle='Optional subtitle.'
                onRequestClose={ () => {
                    // triggered on "<" on left top click or on outside click
                    this.setState({ isPaneOpen: false });
                } }>
                <div>And I am pane content. BTW, what rocks?</div>
                <br />
                <img src='img.png' />
            </SlidingPane>
</div>;
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Apparently, the Slidingpane header is getting hidden under the NavBar. When I remove the navbar, I can see the SlidingPane header, but when I add it, it is getting display beneath it. How do I make my Pane to be independent of the NavBar?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase CSS `z-index` of Slidingpane. If needed you should set `position: "relative"` If you are writing inline styles you can set it like

```
style={{zIndex: "10", position: "relative"}}
```